# Cognitions cannot be self luminous?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya

https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/115370/12/12_chapter%204.pdf

Page 126 says that Shankara refuted the vijnanavada view that cognitions are self luminous.where does he do this in his works and what are the gist of shankara’s arguments against the vijnanavadin position mentioned here?

What does it mean for a cognition to be self luminous?

Comment: Please put the exact text from page 126 that you have a question about rather than a link. it is unclear if your interpretation in your question is correct or not. Shankara did not criticize Vijnanavada - he did criticize Svatantra-Vijnanavada. I also think you are conflating to different meaning of the same word - Cognition and cognitions. Please provide more detail to your question.

Comment: I can’t at this moment as I only have a IPhone to post my questions on.I will do so tomorrow.